# node, unit-testing and mocking with sinon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unit-testing

So I am using a test suite of Chai, rewire, sinon, and sinon-chai to test some node javascript. This is my first time trying to set this up so I could use some pointers. The function I am trying to test looks like so :

```
UserRoles.get = function(ccUrl, namespace, environment, ccToken, authPath) {
    var crowdControl = new CrowdControl(ccUrl, namespace, environment, ccToken, authPath);
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        crowdControl.get().then(resolve).fail(reject).done();
    });
};
```

Inside a document that exports as UserRoles. So I have the initial set up working fine, where I am having troubles is mocking to test this function. I'm trying to mock the new CrowdContol part so my attempt to do that looks like so : https://jsfiddle.net/d5dczyuk/ .

so I'm trying out the

```
testHelpers.sinon.stub(CrowdControl, "UserRoles");
```

to intercept and stub

```
var CrowdControl = require('./crowdcontrol');
```

then just running

```
userRoles.get;

console.log(CrowdControl);
```

And it seems the stub is not being called ( it logs it's a stub but not that it has been called). I will also need to stub the  crowdControl.get() hopefully too, however I was trying to get this simple part working first. Not sure what I need to be doing differently to get this to work here. This is my first time unit testing in node, I've done a bunch in angular where I could just "mock" the CrowdControl, but I'm not sure how it works in node.

Just to clarify I am just checking if CrowControl will be called with those vars passing in, should I just stub it? but I also want to mock the crowdControl so I can force what the get returns.

Edit: here is my second attempt : https://jsfiddle.net/5m5jwk5q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) for this kind of testing. With proxyquire you can stub out require'd dependencies from the modules you're trying to test. So in your case you could do:

```
var crowdControlSpy = sinon.spy();

// Makes sure that when ./user-roles tries to require ./crowdcontrol
// our controlled spy is passed, instead of the actual module.
var UserRoles = proxyquire('./user-roles', {
    './crowdcontrol': crowdControlSpy
});

UserRoles.get(...);
expect(crowdControlSpy).to.have.been.called;
```